# Microsoft Purview - how to delete a Business Glossary

Tags: azure, azure-purview

**Question**: In a `MS Purview`, how can we delete a Business Glossary or rename it? There may be cases where you incorrectly created a Business Glossary or you had a spelling mistake, how can we rectify that mistake?

I am unable to delete a Business Glossary in a `MS Purview` account. The document [Create and manage glossary terms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/how-to-create-manage-glossary-term) from MS Purview team explains how to delete Business Glossary Terms but not a Business Glossary.

Answer (score 1):

As with most things in Azure, if you don't see the functionality you are looking for in the portal, you need to look at the **REST API** or **PowerShell**.  Here is how to do it in the REST API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/glossary/delete-glossary?tabs=HTTP

As for PowerShell, I am not seeing any native cmdlets to delete a glossary but there is a tool on the Azure GitHub page that will allow you to make the REST API calls using PowerShell.  You can view that here:

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Purview-API-PowerShell